# formating of a question after posting it on StackApps

Tags: support, markdown, homepage

I have posted a question on StackApps. When I went to [Newest Questions - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions), the formatting was wrong. Snapshot added:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the way that post was formatted. For the front page, all layout is stripped, so no bold, italics, code blocks, MathJax, etc.

As you can see, at the time of writing, [your post](https://stackapps.com/revisions/6804/1) was:

> What is the use of `min`and `max` parameter in a [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) call? As it returns [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)!

Which is in code:

```
What is the use of `min`and `max` parameter in a [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) call? As it returns [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)!
```

Stripped, this is:

> What is the use of minand max parameter in a /me call? As it returns user!

You forgot a space, which you [corrected yourself](https://stackapps.com/revisions/6804/2) in a later revision of the post. That's all.